# Is it proper to say "nor scarce" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, grammar

> Oh, were you never a schoolboy,
>   And did you never train,
>   And feel that swelling of the heart
>   You never can feel again?
>
> Did you never meet, far down the street,
>   With plumes and banners gay,
>   While the kettle, for the kettledrum,
>   Played your march, march away?
>
> It seems to me but yesterday,
>   **Nor scarce** so long ago,
>   Since all our school their muskets took,
>   To charge the fearful foe.

Regarding the third paragraph, Oxford Dictionary states that *hardly* and *scarcely* should not be used with not or other negatives, e.g. *can't hardly*. Is that proper to use **nor** before **scarce**?

And is it right to use "long ago since..."?

I can't make out the structure of this paragraph though the meaning seems clear to me.

Comment: It's okay. The *nor* is not related to *scarce*, but implies "not even".

Answer (score 1):

Because this is poetry, this sentence is allowed.  In a typical English sentence, we would probably say something like "It doesn't even seem as long as yesterday" instead.

Answer (score 1):

It is an atypical usage for two reasons:

- "Nor" is usually paired with "neither" or some other negative. In this example, "and" would be more common.
- As you note in your question, you wouldn't normally use a negative with "scarce".

That being said, the usage is fine because it is a poem and poems are allowed to break any rules they wish. The meaning is simply, "It seems to me but yesterday, and not so long ago, ..."